# What statistical test should I use for this situation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, mean

I've got three groups A,B,C. Each has a different number of records and I have calculated the mean for each group. Now I want to know if these means are equal or not? What statistical test should I be doing?

```
Group   No.ofrec  Mean
A       100       10
B       200        5
C       300       20
```

Comment: Do you have the original data still, or are you able to calculate standard deviation?

Comment: These three means are not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that your data are continuous, you can use an [ANOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) for this situation.

Comment: @GungIt seems that the data is categorical. May be  ANOVA could be used if translate the number of records  into the proportions.

Comment: @subhashc.davar, it is not very clear in the question, but I interpret `No.ofrec` as the $n$ for each group, & `Mean` as the mean of the response variable. W/ $n$s that large, even if the (w/i group) data are not very normal, you should be OK to run an ANOVA if the data are continuous.

Comment: I have rechecked the dataset. Your response is valid. It is a valid case for ANOVA test